# MySQL Compare between 2 Tables then add results

Tags: mysql

I have a table with the next structure

Table A:

```
| Id  |   1     |     2    |     3     |
|-----|---------|----------|-----------|
|   1 | 00:05:00| 00:10:00 | (null)    |
|   2 | 00:10:00|  (null)  | (null)    |
```

Table B

```
| Id  |   col   |Expected  |
|-----|---------|----------|
|   1 |     1   | 00:06:00 |
|   2 |     2   | 00:12:00 |
|   3 |     3   | 00:22:00 |
```

I am trying to make a sum depending on the actual value on the rows of table A in comparison to the expected on table B

```
Select 
    Id, (Select ??????? From (Select TiempoStd from B)as Stime) as Time
From
   A
```

Basically i want to make a comparison between the 2 tables to see which one is greater and add that to the next one.

I cant manage to understand how to call a specific value under my temp table Stime.

i am not that familiar with SQL so thats why i cant get this, the logic is something like this. in where the question marks are on the Query

```
ADDTIME(IF(A.1>(Stime.Expected where col = 1),A.1,(Stime.Expected where col = 1)),
ADDTIME(IF(A.2>(Stime.Expected where col = 2),A.2,(Stime.Expected where col = 2)),
IF(A.3>(Stime.Expected where col = 3),A.3,(Stime.Expected where col = 3))
```

`Stime.Expected where col = 3` is a bad syntax right? but i hope you get the point of the logic im trying to make here.

so the output would be like this

```
| Id  |   Time  |
|-----|---------|
|   1 | 00:40:00|
|   2 | 00:44:00|
```

Comment: You really should use the same structure in both tables. If you change table 1 so the columns are different rows, you can do an ordinary JOIN.

Comment: @Barmar how so? i dont think i get what you are trying to say, might be a solution

Comment: @Barmar i will always have the same amount of rows in table B than the amount of columns(apart from Id) in table A

Comment: if i just could access the results as you would if it where an array, my logic would be something like this.`(SELECT ADDTIME(IF(TiempoStd[0]>A.1,TiempoStd[0],A.1),ADDTIME(IF(TiempoStd[1]>A.2,TiempoStd[1],A.2),IF(TiempoStd[2]>A.3,TiempoStd[2],A.3)) From (Select TiempoStd from Procesos)as ti) as Cierre`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This made the trick, i got help from some friends and got to it, gives the desired result.

```
SELECT 
    A.Id, 
    addtime(
        addtime( 
            ifnull(Case when A.1 > E.Expected1 Then A.1 else E.expected1 end,'00:00:00') , 
            ifnull(Case when A.2 > E.Expected2 Then A.2 else E.expected2 end,'00:00:00') 
        ), ifnull(Case when A.3 > E.Expected3 Then A.3 else E.expected3 end,'00:00:00')
    ) as Time
From TableA A, (
SELECT 
    sum(case when col=1 Then Expected else 0 end) as Expected1, 
    sum(case when col=2 Then Expected else 0 end) as Expected2, 
    sum(case when col=3 Then Expected else 0 end) as Expected3
From TableB ) as E
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `UNION` to convert table A to a table with separate rows for each column, then join this with table B.

```
select *
FROM TableB AS b
JOIN (SELECT Id, 1 AS col, a.1 AS Time
      FROM TableA as a
      UNION 
      SELECT Id, 2 AS col, a.2 AS Time
      FROM TableA AS a
      UNION 
      SELECT Id, 3 AS col, a.3 AS Time
      FROM TableA AS a) AS a
ON a.Id = b.Id AND a.col = b.col
```

Comment: so, i tried that on this fiddle, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d33072/1 and i dont get what you are trying to get :/

Comment: I don't understand how you're trying to combine the times. My answer just shows how to rearrange the tables so you can join them.